# get() immediately after obtaining ListenableFuture

Tags: java, asynchronous, asynchttpclient

If I get a `ListenableFuture<X>` when calling an external system using the [`AsyncHttpClient`](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client), and I call `get()` immediately - will the current thread not wait until the async thread is ready with a Response? If that is true, what is the benefit of using `AsyncHttpClient`?

```
AsyncHttpClient httpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
ListenableFuture<Response> futureResponse = httpClient.execute(url, payload, headers);

// If this is immediately on next line, am I getting any benefit?
Response response = futureResponse.get();
```

Comment: Yes, it will wait until the `Future` completes. There is no benefit in `AsyncHttpClient` here.

Comment: If you want to execute 2 or more requests at the same time, you can execute them concurrently and then wait for them to complete. That will only take as long as the longest-duration request, rather than the total time of all requests added together.

Comment: If I have 1 async request made per main thread - then will each main thread  remain blocked until async IO completes ? Does that mean - I can not get benefit of async client at all ?

Comment: How can you have multiple "main threads" ? You designate something "main" because it's the *main* one. Not sure what you mean with your comment.

Comment: Apologies for confusion. By main thread, I meant the thread that is serving the original request. In my case, client calls system A, and System A acts like a proxy and sends request to system B using AsyncHttpClient

Answer (score 7):

Per the [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interface contract, which `ListenableFuture` implements, `get()` returns the result of the `Future`, and thusly must block until necessary computations are complete.

Executing `get()` immediately after a `Future` call would give you no benefit, if system A calls system B with an async request, calling get right after will cause system A to wait.

If you want system A to keep doing things while B is processing the request, you may wish to add a Callback or Listener to the ListenableFuture so that A can do what it needs to do when B comes back (the ability to do this is kind of the reason why  `ListenableFuture` exists, as a matter of fact).